# Finding combinations of list of lists that add up to a target number

Tags: c#, linq, list, combinations

I've got an interesting issue I'm trying to solve. My knowledge of Linq is honestly very shallow and I'm pretty certain this is the sort of problem that would be most elegantly solved with a Linq based solution but I've attempted a few things so far with what little knowledge I have to little success.

Here's the skinny: I have a List of decimal Lists and I want to find a combination from the lists adding up to a target decimal using only one element from each list. To clarify:

```
List<List<decimal>> parentList; // this is the main list I'm drawing from
List<decimal> childList { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 }; // each list inside of the main list would look something like this
```

So if my parentList contains five of the childLists, I need to find a combination that only uses one item each list once. This doesn't mean I can't use the same value twice, if parentList[0] and parentList[1] both contain 3 and I'm adding to 6, {3,3} would be a valid solution. However, if parentList[0] were { 1 , 2 , 3 } and parentList[1] were { 4 }, the only valid solution to add to 6 woudl be {2 , 4}, since the second list doesn't contain 3.

I hope this all makes sense and I'm not asking too much. I don't mind just being oriented in the direction of a solution, a push in the right direction as opposed to the whole answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with Linq but you can always brute force a problem like this. take every number in list on and add it with every combination of numbers from the next list and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others has already stated, `LINQ` is not suitable for task like this. Such complex `LINQ` would not be good both from maintenance and performance perspective.

But I could not stop until I made my inner geek happy! You asked for it...

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<decimal>> FindCombinations(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<decimal>> listOfLists, decimal target)
{
    return listOfLists.Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<decimal>(), 1),
        (acc, seq) =>
            from accseq in acc
            from item in seq
            select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}))
        .Where(x => x.Sum(y => y) == target);
}
```

And here is console test application:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var target = 12;
    var listOfLists = new List<List<decimal>>()
    {
        new List<decimal> { 1, 2, 3 },
        new List<decimal> { 3, 4, 5 },
        new List<decimal> { 5, 6, 7 },
    };

    foreach (var combination in FindCombinations(listOfLists, target))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", string.Join(" + ", combination.Select(y => y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))), target);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you would solve using recursion and not Linq. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<decimal>> listOfLists = new List<List<decimal>>()
            {
                new List<decimal>() { 1, 2, 3 },
                new List<decimal>() { 3, 4, 5 },
                new List<decimal>() { 5, 6, 7 },
            };

            PrintAllCombinationsForTargetValue(listOfLists, 12);
        }

        private static void PrintAllCombinationsForTargetValue(List<List<decimal>> listOfLists, decimal targetValue)
        {
            Stack<decimal> currentCombination = new Stack<decimal>();
            FindNextElement(listOfLists, targetValue, 0, 0, currentCombination);
        }

        private static void FindNextElement(List<List<decimal>> listOfLists, decimal targetValue, int listIndex, decimal trackingValue, Stack<decimal> currentCombination)
        {
            List<decimal> currentList = listOfLists[listIndex];
            foreach (decimal currentValue in currentList)
            {
                decimal currentTrackingValue = trackingValue + currentValue;
                currentCombination.Push(currentValue);

                if (currentTrackingValue < targetValue && listIndex < listOfLists.Count - 1)
                {
                    // There is still la chance that we can get what we want. Let's go to the next list.
                    FindNextElement(listOfLists, targetValue, listIndex + 1, currentTrackingValue, currentCombination);
                }
                else if (currentTrackingValue == targetValue && listIndex == listOfLists.Count - 1)
                {
                    // Found a valid combination!
                    currentCombination.Reverse().ToList().ForEach(element => Console.Write(element + " "));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                currentCombination.Pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with recursion.  This will find one combination that sums up to the target, using one value from each list, or null if none exists.

```
public static List<decimal> CombinationSumMatches(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<decimal>> lists, 
    decimal target)
{
    if (lists.Any())
    {
        var firstList = lists.First();
        if (lists.Skip(1).Any())
        {
            foreach (var num in firstList)
            {
                var newTarget = target - num;
                var subCombination = lists.Skip(1).CombinationSumMatches(newTarget);
                if (subCombination != null)
                {
                    subCombination.Insert(0, num);
                    return subCombination;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (firstList.Contains(target))
            {
                return new List<decimal> { target };
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This will first check if there are any lists.  If there are then it looks at the first one and sees if there are more.  If there are more it goes through each number of the first list and subtracts that value from the target and does a recursive call on the remaining lists.  If there is a non null answer it inserts the number and returns.  Now if there is only one list then it just checks the list for the target and returns a list with that target value if it finds it.  If there are no lists, or only one without the target, or nothing that matches the sub combinations then it will just return `null`.